# Why separate URL from GET parameters with a slash /

Tags: php, html, forms, rest, routes

When you submit a form using `GET`, the URL becomes `http://site.com/form?a=1&b=2`.

**Question:** Why do some sites use the url like `http://site.com/form/?a=1&b=2` where the `GET` parameters are seperated from the main URL *(incorrect term?)* by a slash `/`.

Example: `http://www.nastygal.com/shoes/?filterIDList=10&minPrice=0&maxPrice=1000`

Comment: same question i wanted to ask +1

Comment: Because it doesn't matter?

Comment: You might want to take a look here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/ - `/form` might refer to `/form.php` with extensions hidden and `/form/` might be `/form/index.php` using a url rewrite.

Comment: The "/" actually has nothing to do with the GET parameters and everything to do with the url path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the use case, `/shoes/` may not be just another `GET` argument, but instead a directory on the site.

For example, `http://site.com/form` could evaluate to `http://site.com/form/index.php`. So in those cases, it is required to format it this way since `shoes` is a directory in the site base.

Answer (score 0):

The "/form" could refer to:

- "form.php" with file extensions hidden.
- "form" - a file with no extension.
- "/form/index.php" - a directory index page (assuming the directory index is "index.php")
- a URL rewrite to almost anything else on the server.

Its worth noting that this doesn't affect the GET parameters in any way, websites that do this may be using it as a simple way to make their URLs more easily readable to the user.